# Symfony 2 Edit Action not populating form fields

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm attempting to create an edit action for a user address entity but whenever you load the page it doesn't seem to load the associated data.  below is the code for my controller and view.

Profile Controller:

```
public function addressEditAction($id) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || $user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        if ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $address = $em->getRepository('SCWDesignsBundle:UserAddresses')->getAddressById($user->getId(), $id);
            if (!$address) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Could not find address id: "%s"', $id));
            }

            $form = $this->createForm(new UserAddressesFormType(), $address);

            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
                $form->bind($request);
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $utilites = new Utilities;
                    $address->setPhone($utilites->stripPhoneNumbers($address->getPhone()));
                    $em->persist($address);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show'));
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('SCWDesignsBundle:Profile\Address:new.html.twig', array(
            'active_page' => 'profile',
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));  
    }
```

View:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'SCWDesignsBundle' %}

{% block modal_block %}
<div class="item-box">
    <h2>Address Details</h2>

    {% include 'SCWDesignsBundle:Default:form_errors.html.twig' %}

    <form action="{{ path('scw_designs_address_add') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="scw_designs_address_new clearfix">
        <div class="address-new">
            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="first-name">{{ 'profile.first_name'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.first_name) }}
                </div>          
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="last-name">{{ 'profile.last_name'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.last_name) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="address">{{ 'profile.address'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.address_one) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.address_two) }}
                </div>              
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="city">{{ 'profile.city'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.city) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="country">{{ 'profile.country'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.country) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="state">{{ 'profile.state'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.state) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="zipcode">{{ 'profile.zipcode'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.zipcode, { 'attr': { 'class': 'zipcodeUS' }}) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-label">
                    <label for="phone">{{ 'profile.phone'|trans }}: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ form_widget(form.phone, { 'attr': { 'class': 'phoneUS' }}) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-button-wrapper">
            {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn-submit primary-button">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In the profilecontroller you can see me call a method from the entities respository, here's the var_dump of the array $address:

$address:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
  array (size=11)
    'id' => string '4' (length=1)
    'firstName' => string 'Bruce' (length=5)
    'lastName' => string 'Wayne' (length=5)
    'addressOne' => string '123 Gotham Lane' (length=15)
    'addressTwo' => null
    'city' => string 'Gotham' (length=6)
    'country' => string 'USA' (length=3)
    'zipcode' => string '51478' (length=5)
    'phone' => string '3344796239' (length=10)
    'code' => string 'NH' (length=2)
    'state' => string 'New Hampshire' (length=13)
```

So as you can see I've gotten the proper data from the database, I've followed the instructions on binding the data to the form object, it just simply doesn't persist into the view.  I've tried multiple things but can't seem to get it working.  Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting from the repository a two dimensional `$address` array when the form is expecting a single object probably.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll take a look at the the returned value tonight!

Comment: I can't believe this was the actual problem... Thank you very much.